# NSTableView: only numberOfRowsInTableView: datasource is called

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I met a problem about the `NSTableView`, and it is like:
one datasource of tableview is called:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.dataArray count];
}
```

But this one is never called:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    // the code 
}
```

I have checked the the array really had data, and also checked the 
`[NSTableView reloadData]` was called in the main thread.

SO I'm totally lost about this weird problem.
Would any one give some tips?
thanks!

Comment: are you using a view based table view ?

Comment: have you  checked whether you inform about the delegate and date source methods in .h file and connect the data source outlet of tableView to your class in .xib file

Comment: Did you log [self.dataArray count] to check that it's not returning 0? Also, is your table cell based or view based?

Comment: @Samir,@rdelmar  It is view based. I tried to use cell based but had the same problem.

Comment: @VigneshKumar, I connected the data source and delegate in the nib. And I also printed them when -[tableview numberOfRowsInTableView:] was invoked.

Comment: @scorpiozj why don't you create a dummy project for TableView and implement those two methods returning an integer for number of rows and a sample textValue for objectValueForTableView ,coz I did the same and Got these delegate methods called with out fail.If You also get this thing worked you can compare main project and dummy project to find what u have missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved the initial code from `awakeFromNib` to the `init`, and it called correctly. But I still don't know the real reason. I guess it matters with the life-cycle of the view because the class which has the tableview is a subclass of `NSObject` and not of `NSViewController`.

Comment: My problem was that I called "setDataSource:self" before populating the array, thus my app invoked "numberOfRowsInTable" before it had anything! Simply moving the "setDataSource:self" down (It is now the last thing in my "awakeFromNib" solved the issue). "init" is called before "awakeFromNib" (The former being called when the object is created, the latter when the nib loads). That's probably why that worked for you. Same thing, just populate the array before setting the data source!