# NSTableView not all datasource methods are getting calls

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, nstableview

I have created a tableview programmatically and added column, delegate and datasource successfully. But the problem is that only one method of datasource is getting called that is

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
```

As the question asked here:
[NSTableView: only numberOfRowsInTableView: datasource is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245113/nstableview-only-numberofrowsintableview-datasource-is-called)

But there is no specific answer available to this question.

Here is my code for creating the TableView:

```
customTableView=[[NSTableView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
[customTableView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
customTableView.delegate=self;
customTableView.dataSource=self;
NSTableColumn * column1 = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Col1"];
[column1 setWidth:frame.size.width];
[customTableView addTableColumn:column1];
[self addSubView:customTableView];
[customTableView reloadData];
```

Moreover, all my datasource methods are in same class.

EDIT: I am creating this TableView in a separate view class, not in ViewController or AppDelegate.

Comment: Provide the code that you are using inside numberOfRowsInTableView. Also specify where you are initializing the data (maybe NSArray) which is what went wrong in the link you provided.

Comment: above code is in awakeFromNib or in init?

Comment: are you using custom tableview

Comment: @Rakesh: I am just returning 10 as a number for initial testing.

Comment: @AKV: It is in init method only.

Comment: try moving it to awakeFromNib

Comment: @Ravindra Bagale: Its just an instance of NSTableView created programmatically as u can see in question.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Is there any necessary condition to put this code in awakeFromNib? If yes, can you please let me know in detail??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the piece of code where you add the table view as a sub view to the window.

Assuming the object in which you create the table view has a `window` property. The following would do the trick:

```
[[self.window contentView] addSubview:customTableView];
```

Comment: That thing I Have done in my appdelegate class. I am creating this table view in a separate view file and putting that view into window in appdelegate.

Comment: And question actually is why not all datasource methods are getting called, y only one? I have checked it by putting break points.

Comment: in which method of the view have you added the lines of code. Coz i tried out this code without the above line of code and the same problem happens. Maybe the reloadData fires before the tableview added to the window or some change in order of execution of methods that is causing the datasource methods to be not fired.

Comment: Actually, Firstly i tried without calling reloadData method, but problem was same. So, I called this method to see that data-source methods might get called this time. But still same result.

Comment: and in which method of the view are you writing the code to create the tableview

Comment: where are you using this view? When are you initializing it? Are you adding the table view as the sub view to it? If you could add more details to your question, it would be easier for people to answer it. If not me, for someone else who knows better. Anyway i think this is happening because of some order in which things are being initialized or added.

Comment: I forgot the line where I was adding tableView as subview. I have edited the code above.

Comment: Well i tried out doing the same, creating a custom view in AppDelegate, overriding the 'initWithFrame:' (not init method) to add the table view  and it works. Only difference is the 'addSubView:' was changed to 'addSubview:'. I assume thats a typo here.

Comment: Sorry for typing mistake. But I don't know Y this thing is showing weird behavior to me. I am still stuck at same place since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have written all methods in `init`.

Try moving `setDatasource` & `setDelegate` to `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use set delegate and datasource in awakeFromNib. I am not using any nib file for my views.

Comment: First nib is loaded the init is called.

Comment: currently i dont have mac with me, otherwise i would have checked this issue.

Comment: But as i said, I am nowhere using a nib in my views.